# Google Cloud VPN is not allowing outbound HTTP or SSH into Office Network

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform

We have a new Google Cloud Platform setup. We have successfully created a VPN connection to our office router. We can reach private addresses in Google Cloud from our office and some services from inside GCP can reach into our office network. We have set up kube-dns to use our internal DNS server over the VPN for private resources and for the most part, that's working fine. And, from both containers and the container cluster node VMs, we can ping addresses inside the office network.

But the first app we wish to deploy in Google Container Engine needs HTTPS access to API servers running inside the office network behind the firewall. These HTTPS connections (tested with wget and curl) just hang. No data is returned. I've done a traffic capture on the office router and I can see packets coming in and going back out the tunnel as expected. I also tried regular HTTP and SSH connetions outbound from Google into our office. I tried from inside a running container and from the Container Engine cluster node (COS image) itself. Nothing but ping and DNS are working from Google reaching into the office network.

There are no Egress firewall rules in GCP. The office router policy is presently allowing all traffic across the VPN. I've found a couple of other posts similar to our situation, but they were older and most of them reference fixes to GCP that have been made in the meantime, others discuss complex iptables solutions.

So, we are totally blocked on our first cloud deployment. How can we troubleshoot the networking in GCP? It seems like the returning packets are just not getting routed back to their source. Neither DNS nor ping are TCP and of course HTTPS and SSH are TCP. That's the main difference I can identify between what works and what does not. What do we try next?

Comment: I discovered that it was a packet size issue. Not only did the MTU need to be dialed back on our router but also the maximum segment size.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following explains the MTU setting required for Google Cloud VPN.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced#maximum_transfer_unit_mtu_considerations

On our Juniper SSG series routers, I set the MTU on the VPN tunnel virtual interface with:

```
set interface tunnel.3 mtu 1460
```

However the solution required more than just MTU, because on a VPN, the encryption adds overhead after packets are broken into MTU sized pieces, or at least I think that's how it works. Again on our routers, we had to apply the following configuration commands to configure appropriate packet sizes for VPN traffic:

```
set flow tcp-mss 1350
set flow vpn-tcp-mss 1300
```

I did not spend time searching for the perfect numerical values in those commands, nor did I test if only one of those was actually required, but with both of those values set, our VPN started working as expected.